# Error with Access VBA Recordset to Find First on a Different Form?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, dao, recordset, findfirst

I created a pop-up form in access, to search for a record and go to it on the main entry form.  The pop-up "find" form has a listbox with all the records that are in the main entry form, and the first column of that listbox is the ID on the main entry form.  This is a hidden column on the listbox.

The user can type something into an unbound textbox, which will filter the listbox, and then once they see the record, they want, they should be able to double-click a row of the listbox, and it should take them to that record on the main entry form.  I am getting an error and not sure why.

This is the code for on double-click of the listbox:

```
Private Sub lstRecords_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


    Set rs = Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.RecordsetClone
    rs.MoveFirst
    rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Forms!frmFindRecords.lstRecords.Column(0)
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        'Display the found record in the form.
        Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.cboJumpToRecord = Forms!frmFindRecords.lstRecords.Column(0)
        Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.cboJumpToRecord.Requery
        cmdClose_Click
    Else
        MsgBox "Weird, I can't find that record. Tell Someone!"
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I try to select something, I get the following error:
Run-time error '2473': The expression |2 you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: |1.

It highlights this line, of the above code:

```
        Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

It is like it doesn't hold onto the recordset from the other form. I can see the main form look like it briefly goes to that record, but then I think that form is checking/resetting it's recordset, when it goes to it, because it has to check a toggle button that sets the status of a filter on that form.

I don't know how to get around it. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I can't find where I found this (lol), but I found this really elegant solution, that seems to work really well:

```
Private Sub lstRecords_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Forms!frmMainEntry.Recordset.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Forms!frmFindRecords.lstRecords.Column(0)
    Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.cboJumpToRecord = Forms!frmFindRecords.lstRecords.Column(0)
    Forms!frmMainEntry.Form.cboJumpToRecord.Requery
    cmdClose_Click
End Sub
```

No more errors!